# How to disable unneeded Java libraries built into RAD Studio?

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-platform, shared-libraries

I am using Delphi 11 CE for developing an app for Android. The libraries automatically added to each project by Delphi are in the project manager, target platform Android and libraries. The list also includes Google Admob files that I want to delete because the Google Playstore no longer accepts my app because these libraries are outdated. According to Embarcadero, the deletion should be done by right-clicking and selecting the Disable function. However, since no submenu appears, it is also not possible to delete or deactivate it. What other options are there?

Comment: "However, since no submenu appears..." It appears OK for me. Are you right-clicking the actual (individual) libraries that you want to disable?

Comment: It might also help to know the exact text from Google Play Store regarding the outdated libraries

Comment: Please read my comment  further down... It seems that Delphi doesn't show the submenue if the library is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of used libraries is stored in project `.dproj` file.

You can manually customize those by editing this file in some text editor.

You can find list of used library entries under `<EnabledSysJars>` tag. Delete the ones you don't want.

There is a separate `<EnabledSysJars>` tag for each Android platform (32-bit and 64-bit)

Comment: After resetting the libraries to standard values (right mouse click on libraries) the content changed and the disable function worked as exspected. Disabled entries appear under <DisabledSysJars> in the project.dproj file. The project came from Delphi 10 and was compiled with Delphi 11. So the old libraries had to be replaced by the new libraries manually.